# Windows Management tool for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I use Sizeup for Mac, which lets me to resize window, and move them to a specific spot. 
It is simply awesome !   http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/

I know there must be something for the Windows 7 ? I just can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product recommendation are threaten as off topic here. But take a look at [WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be as easy as SizeUp...but it seems to do the job. Thanks !  I still don't get the off-topic argument, but whatever. There are always people who think they are smarter. ;-)

Comment: the "off topic" are the rules here. We can't change this.

Comment: It is an excellent free service. I can live with some BS ;)